# [ANDROID]High score saver

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I wish to take a high score of my application 'game' and put it in my main activity(the first one,The menu) as "Highest score: ____" ,
As I understand I can do it with SharedPreferance.
But I can't understand how this is working, where does I 'start it for first time'(Creating it) and so.
Can someone give me a good guide, or/and example how should it has to be done?

Thanks very much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the value:

```
// Get the saved value (or default value if it hasn't been saved yet)
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
int high_score = settings.getInt("highscore_pref", 0);
```

Here's how you can save the value (replace `99` with what you want to save):

```
// Save the value
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("highscore_pref", 99);
editor.apply();
```

As usual, check out [the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Does the file create himself? , can you explan me the background of it, how is it work? .    edit: what the the 'getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);' means what is "MyPrefs" and what 0 means

Comment: Check out the Android [docs on SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more information.

Comment: Done, Thanks! , btw I can call it from any activity I want, or it is for the single activity only?

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help! :>

Comment: Hi dude, as it seems this line: "SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0); " is crushing my app, Do I have to start MyPrefs somewhere? , thanks

Comment: are you trying to call it before the app has started?

Comment: Yep, and I had another mistake lol I fixed them both thank you.

Comment: I don't want to intterapt you, but when I using it, the number sharednumber is not changing, thats mean it stay 0 for the whole time. any idea why?